# Docker on fedora 20(32-bit) not working

Tags: installation, docker, fedora20

As per the documentation at:https://docs.docker.com/installation/fedora/,
I understand its not supported for the 32-bit.(for my system uname -r gives 3.11.10-301.fc20.i686)

But looking at :https://docs.docker.com/installation/binaries/, I downloaded the https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/i386/docker-latest.tgz.

Now after extracting it, when i hit : "docker -d &"  at terminal as su, i get
"This is a client-only binary - running the Docker daemon is not supported."
As per documentation I would have accepted this for Mac OS X and Windows, but I am working on linux.

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Even on Linux, 32-bit support for daemon mode is not a priority ([issue 136](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/136)).

That leaves you with the option of [recompiling docker on i386 32-bits](http://mwhiteley.com/linux-containers/2013/08/31/docker-on-i386.html), and build a 32-bits base image in order to run 32-bits apps containers.